# Help me find $ \lim_{x\to\infty} {x(\pi-2\arctan{x})} $

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Please help me find this limit $$\lim_{x\to\infty} {x(\pi-2\arctan{x})} $$

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers. – This applies to *all* of your questions posted so far.

Comment: So far all your posts have been problem-statement questions. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 2):

Use L'hopital's rule on the function:
$$f(x)=\frac{\pi-2\arctan x}{x^{-1}},$$
given you have $\frac 00$ in the limit.  Then you can attain the result.

Answer (score 0):

The formula
$$\arctan x+\arctan \frac{1}{x}=\frac{\pi}{2}\text{sgn}(x)$$
is valid for $x\ne 0$.
Thus as $x\to +\infty$,
$$x(\pi-\arctan x)=2x\arctan \frac{1}{x}\to 2,$$
while as $x\to -\infty$, we have
$$x(\pi-\arctan x)<\pi x\to -\infty.$$
Since the situation $x\to \infty$ implies both situations $x\to \pm \infty$, the function is sure to have no limit.